# Window base class in MVVM ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am calling to create an `ExampleWindow` from my `ViewModel` externally (In my `WindowService`).

Would it be bad practice if i hand back the `ExampleWindow` as `Window` (base class) to the VM?

Like this:

```
class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public override Window GetExampleWindow()
    {
        return new ExampleWindow();
    }
}
```

In my VM I am getting the `IWindowService` per DI.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us your [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills done..

Comment: Could you please first explain why you would need to do this? This seems like a really bad idea. With MVVM your backend should never need to access the frontend. That's the job of the ViewModel.

Comment: @bic i want to open and close my window in the VM. I thought with this it would be very easy.

Comment: @BobMaier: Sorry, I misunderstood your setup. Yes, passing back a Window instance from your Service to the responsible ViewModel is fine. Disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @bic Are u really sure? I am new MVVM WPF, so I really ned an answer i can rely on.

Comment: @BobMaier: I would recommend going over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and detailing your solution structure with regard to the WindowsService, the Windows themselves and the relationship with the ViewModels.

Comment: If you want to be totally "clean", introduce an interface `IView` with two methods `Open` and `Close` and let your windows implement it. Return an `IView` instance from your `WindowService`. Now, no view-model will be able to do some bad things such as `Window.ShowInTaskbar = false`.